# React Boostrap input form doesn't give any value

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hi everybody Tring to make a form with `Form` provided by `bootstap` but it doesn't work.
If I insert value it doesn't let me type, without value I digit but I can't get the value.

(I have also a Gatsby theme activated)

```
const StandAdd = () => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState({
    title: "",
    kindof: "",
    website: "",
    image01: "",
    image02: "",
    image03: "",
  })

  const { title, kindof, website, image01, image02, image03 } = item

  const handleInputChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setItem({ ...item, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
  }

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    alert(`${title} ${item} ${website}`) // always empty I gat get anything
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form>
          <Form.Group controlId="title">
            {/* <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label> */}
            <Form.Control
              value={titlet} // <-- this blocks the typing
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter Stand's Name"
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>
  <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </form>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default StandAdd
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
<Form.Control
              value="title" // <-- this blocks the typing
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter Stand's Name"
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
```

here you have to provide the name attribute so that your code:

```
setItem({ ...item, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
```

will get some value in `event.target.name`.

So after adding `name` the code will be like:

```
<Form.Control
              type="text"
              name="title"  <---- name added here 
              placeholder="Enter Stand's Name"
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
```

And don't provide a hard-coded value to input like this:

```
value="title"
```

instead use `defaultValue` for providing an initial value.

Comment: I don't have any hardcoded. Sorry but that was just a try to see if value worked with bootstrap

Comment: After providing name attribute, inside `handleInputChange` function put a log and see if `event.target.name` has some value

Comment: I added `name={title}` to From.Control and  `event.target.name` to `handleInputChange` but it doesn't change

Comment: Try this: `name="title"`

Comment: yes! it works!! thanks! can you change your answer with the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide name attribute to <Form.Control> component.